# Random texture coordinates on array

Tags: texturing, uv, modifiers

I modeled some logs that together compose a wall. I modeled one and texturized it, then applied an array modifier. Problem is that they all look the same. is there a way to randomize the texture coordinates on each of them? Or am I forced to copy and paste them "manually" and avoid the array modifier?

Comment: If you use UV coordinates they're going to be identical in all the meshes obviously. But you can often get away with using world space or object space coordinates.

Comment: Quite late to answer, but this might help you out.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0YmpkUeVYg

Answer (score 2):

As of Blender 2.8, there's a UV offset parameter in the Array modifier that should do the trick.  Not exactly random, but it might give you good enough results.

Comment: As in one of the comment-inks above, you can actually make the result as random as you like by not using the UV directly. Instead use the offset-UV to look up into a noise texture. and use whatever you find there as your actual UV.

Answer (score 2):

The answer in comments is what you need, but it is related to color and not coordinate space.  I usually do something like this:

[image]